# Returning data from the find() in mongodb

Tags: mongoose

I have the following code.

```
function getNextFiveFixtures(teamname) {
   var fixtures = fixtureModel.find({
       Home : teamname
   },function(err,doc){
       console.log(doc);
   });
}
```

This print the data on the screen. Though , when i tried to return the data through the following code.

```
function getNextFiveFixtures(teamname) {
   var fixtures = fixtureModel.find({
       Home : teamname
   },function(err,doc){
       return doc;
   });
   return fixtures;
}

var fixture = getNextFiveFixtures('Chelsea');
console.log(fixture);
```

This prints a mongodb object. How to get the result in a variable. Appreciate the help.